# how to invoke javac from windows git shell/gnu makefile

Tags: java, windows, git-shell

I was working home office with my linux box, 
was sure to write portable code. 
Used shell and gnumake and compiled java through

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked --module-path libs/nrjavaserial-4.0.1.jar:libs/jep-3.9.0.jar:libs/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:libs/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar:src/  src/main/de/name/product/Product.java -d target/classes/
```

All ok. 
Now in office with windows 10 but still gnumake, does not work. 
Also from git bash, no.

I would be content as a first step to get it run in gitshell. 
I use `javac 11.0.7` and `2.26.0.windows.1`.

The errors (i cannot show in full because related to customer) 
show that no jar has been accepted:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
       NRSerialPort serial = getSingleSerialPort(baudRate);
        ^
  symbol:   class NRSerialPort
  location: class xxx
```

shows that `libs/nrjavaserial-4.0.1.jar` is not accepted athough present 
and

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        } catch(JepException e) {
                ^
  symbol:   class JepException
  location: class XXX
```

shows that `libs/jep-3.9.0.jar` is not accepted. 
Note that on linux all works fine on an ordinary bash shell.

Maybe separators wrong for windows? 
I always thought, separators are transparent on git bash? 
or only / but not :? 
I tried several combinations, without success.

I suspect all quite easy... right?

Comment: you are right. i will edit

Answer (score 0):

You've guessed right, you need to use different separators on Windows.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html

> In the following lists of options, an argument of path represents a
>   search path, composed of a list of file system locations separated by
>   the platform path separator character, (semicolon ; on Windows, or
>   colon : on other systems.) Depending on the option, the file system
>   locations may be directories, JAR files or JMOD files.

If you want portability, ease-of-use and maintainability, use something like ant, maven or gradle.